# Response.Redirect stuck on 302 infinite loop in Session_Start

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I am facing this issue while migrating an HTML page to ASPX.

In Global.asax

```
Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        '... Logic to calculate valid user
        If Not (validUser) Then
          Response.Redirect("~\Errors\UserError_Test.aspx")
        'Response.Redirect("~\Errors\UserError.htm")
        Session.Abandon()
        End If
End Sub
```

The aspx page is just a copy of the original html page which itself is a simple page with a link for the user, albeit based on an app key from web.config (the reason I am migrating to aspx)

Now,as the aspx page is requested, it gets stuck in an infinite loop of 302 status code. While debugging, the Session_Start keeps getting hit repeatedly in a loop.

Based on what I could research about the issue I have tried following until now:

- checked web.config and iis for authorization setting which is set to Allow Anonymous
- tried to load the apsx page in the html itself using iframe, but it still keeps getting into the infinite loop
- checked if any other page of same name exists and is being called but nothing like that
- tried adding Response.End() after the redirection

Comment: You could avoid doing the redirection if it's on the error page: `If Not (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath).Equals("UserError_Test", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) AndAlso Not (validUser) Then`.

Comment: Or rather, as the Page object is not available in Session_Start, `If Not (System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Request.Url.LocalPath).Equals("UserError_Test", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) AndAlso Not (validUser) Then`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton The solution works. Thank you very much. Please excuse my ignorance on this but is the additional check for Request URL something I would be better off always doing for Response.Redirect ?

Comment: You're welcome :) In general, you would be redirecting to a different page from the current one, so you wouldn't usually have to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid doing the redirection if it's on the error page:

```
If Not (System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Request.Url.LocalPath).Equals("UserError_Test", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) AndAlso Not (validUser) Then
```